# How can I leave a Discord server using a user token?

Tags: javascript, html, discord, token

Using a user token, how can I have the user leave a Discord server? I wanted to make a website where you put your user token and it will leave discord server.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1):

**As per [discord terms](https://discord.com/developers/docs/intro) of service the use of "self bots" is not allowed**

A "self bot" is when a normal discord user account is automated in some way, for example leaving all servers or automatically sending messages.

Another reason why this is not recommended is the security concern, how does the user know that your website won't steal their token and "hack" their account?

Saying that there is of course a way to do it neglecting terms of service and user safety. A starting point would be the [discord API](https://discord.com/developers/docs/intro) or a discord library like [discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/). I won't spoon-feed you code, do some research your self and if you encounter a more specific problem come back and ask.

Comment: it wont be public it will be only for myself

Comment: Okay @Amogus but the first reason still applies. It is against the terms and can get you banned if detected. But if you are willing to take the risk go ahead and try. 

Also, if you found that I answered your question please accept it by clicking the checkmark under the vote button.

Comment: but im looking for code for it ii tried using api but it doesnrt worked